# Detect first occurrences between two variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable, find-occurrences

I would like to count the first occurrences of two variables (IPC and 2IPC) in R, leaving out cases in which the two variables are the same (e.g. !IPC == 2IPC).

Here is an example of dataset:

```
**date  IPC     2IPC    occurrence** 
 1968   G01S    Na      1
 1969   G01N    G01S    1
 1969   B62D    B43L    1
 1969   G01S    Na      0
 1970   G01S    G01C    1
 1970   G01S    H04B    1
 1970   G01S    H04B    0
 1971   G01S    H01S    1
 1971   G01S    G01S    0
 1972   H04N    H04N    0
 1972   G01S    G01S    0
 1972   G01S    G01S    0
```

I used the Excel function COUNTIFS which create a dummy (occurrence) for the first occurrences between two variables. Is it possible to use dplyr for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and assuming that `Na` values are valid values and not NAs, you may run the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
group_by(IPC,X2IPC) %>%
mutate(N_occurences=row_number()) %>% 
mutate(FirstOccurrence=case_when(
    (IPC!=X2IPC) & N_occurences==1 ~ 1,
    (IPC==X2IPC) | N_occurences!=1 ~ 0
))
```

You'll get the following result:

```
   X..date IPC   X2IPC occurrence.. N_occurences FirstOccurrence
     <int> <chr> <chr>        <int>        <int>           <dbl>
 1    1968 G01S  Na               1            1            1.00
 2    1969 G01N  G01S             1            1            1.00
 3    1969 B62D  B43L             1            1            1.00
 4    1969 G01S  Na               0            2            0   
 5    1970 G01S  G01C             1            1            1.00
 6    1970 G01S  H04B             1            1            1.00
 7    1970 G01S  H04B             0            2            0   
 8    1971 G01S  H01S             1            1            1.00
 9    1971 G01S  G01S             0            1            0   
10    1972 H04N  H04N             0            1            0   
11    1972 G01S  G01S             0            2            0   
12    1972 G01S  G01S             0            3            0
```

Whether you want the same data frame in you OP, just run the code:

```
mydf %>% 
    group_by(IPC,X2IPC) %>%
    mutate(N_occurences=row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(FirstOccurrence=case_when(
        (IPC!=X2IPC) & N_occurences==1 ~ 1,
        (IPC==X2IPC) | N_occurences!=1 ~ 0
    )) %>%
    select(1:3,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
transform(dat,occurence=as.numeric(!duplicated(dat[2:3])&(IPC!=X2IPC)))
   date  IPC X2IPC occurence
1  1968 G01S    Na         1
2  1969 G01N  G01S         1
3  1969 B62D  B43L         1
4  1969 G01S    Na         0
5  1970 G01S  G01C         1
6  1970 G01S  H04B         1
7  1970 G01S  H04B         0
8  1971 G01S  H01S         1
9  1971 G01S  G01S         0
10 1972 H04N  H04N         0
11 1972 G01S  G01S         0
12 1972 G01S  G01S         0
```

DATA:

```
dat=structure(list(date = c(1968L, 1969L, 1969L, 1969L, 1970L, 1970L, 
1970L, 1971L, 1971L, 1972L, 1972L, 1972L), IPC = c("G01S", "G01N", 
"B62D", "G01S", "G01S", "G01S", "G01S", "G01S", "G01S", "H04N", 
"G01S", "G01S"), X2IPC = c("Na", "G01S", "B43L", "Na", "G01C", 
"H04B", "H04B", "H01S", "G01S", "H04N", "G01S", "G01S")), .Names = c("date", 
"IPC", "X2IPC"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```